# react-native: Organizing children in a parent view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this view with 'cards' in it.
When I add a component that will not fully display in the view, I would like it to move to the next line.

This is my card component:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      borderRadius: 9,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 9,
      margin: 9,
    }}
    onPress={this.props.onPress}
  >

    <Image style={{
      borderRadius: 9,
      opacity: 3,
      width: 93,
      height: 93,
      tintColor: '#976D2B'
    }}

      source={this.props.source}
    />

    <Text style={{
      borderRadius: 9,
      color: '#63461E', //brown
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 16,
      textAlign: 'center',
    }}>
      {this.props.text}
    </Text>

  </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the screen code:

```
 <View 
                        style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}
                    >

                        {/*card 1*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('General')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'General Info'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 2*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('Grades')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Grades'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 3*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('Grades')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Lunch Menu'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 4*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('Grades')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Bell Schedules'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                    </View>
```

*Sorry the indentations got messed up when I pasted

And for some background, I am using react navigation.

Currently the four cards that exist, 3 of them are in plain view, however, the fourth is half off-screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using `flexWrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using

```
 flexWrap: 'wrap'
```

like Nimrod suggested